# how to release memory when using SVGKit in iOS7

Tags: ios7, svgkit

SVGKit is very powerful for displaying SVG image,while it cannot release the memory  after loaded some SVG images,is there anyone encountered this problem and your advise will be appreciated
. thanks very much!